# Toilet mounted in concrete pad

Tags: bathroom, concrete, toilet

The toilet in the basement bathroom was mounted into a pad of concrete. Over the years the concrete has bored out around the screw so the toilet rocks. What could I use to fill the hole?

Comment: pic of the area could help in getting a better idea of your exact issue.  Also , where are you in the world?  Are you in the Us with standard plumbing, or somewhere where things are done differently?

Answer (score 1):

Pictures are always nice so we can see what you see. Think about getting longer screws and fill the existing holes with some epoxy concrete patch and adding a few extra screws. Since the toilet has been rocking, it would be a great time to replace the wax ring.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the toilet is mounted, you may need a [repair ring](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Oatey-7-in-L-Circle-Round-Stainless-Steel-Ring/50315043?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_142_Pipe-Fittings-_-50315043-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjwz8emBhDrARIsANNJjS4LACAsx5B5iHlOPbZvLPA_40dL5V40C2DSyJowjMkcJ0QWSGqqpZMaAtQDEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Or, you just need to [epoxy](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/paint-and-supplies/tape-glues-and-adhesives/glues-and-epoxy/12430?store=15404&gclid=Cj0KCQjwz8emBhDrARIsANNJjS6ethh3JlJ35SVLIsSL1oT2hMIsTNxgY8epAnEdNByY9PQO8wdGK9IaAosbEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) the bolt to the concrete.

With either it would be wise to use a new seal as well.